# Include newly added data sources into route Data Source object without restarting the application server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

Implemented  Spring's AbstractRoutingDatasource by dynamically determining the actual DataSource based on the current context.
Refered this article : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source.

Here on spring boot application start up . Created a map of contexts to datasource objects to configure our AbstractRoutingDataSource. All these client  context details are fetched from a database table.

```
@Bean
    @DependsOn("dataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource routeDataSource() {

        RoutingDataSource routeDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();

        DataSource defaultDataSource = (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource");

        List<EstCredentials> credentials = LocalDataSourcesDetailsLoader.getAllCredentails(defaultDataSource); // fetching from database table

        localDataSourceRegistrationBean.registerDataSourceBeans(estCredentials);

        routeDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource);
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

        for (Credentials credential : credentials) {
            targetDataSources.put(credential.getEstCode().toString(),
                    (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean(credential.getEstCode().toString()));
        }
        routeDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        return routeDataSource;
    }
```

The problem  is if i add a new client details, I cannot get that in  routeDataSource. Obvious reason is that these values are set on start up.

How can I achieve to add new client context and I had to re intialize the routeDataSource object.

Planning to write a service to get all the client context newly added and reset the routeDataSource object, no need to restart the server each time any changes in the client details.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: oracle database

Answer (score 1):

So this will depend on how much you know about the datasources to be added, but you could set this up as a [multi-tenant project](https://github.com/bcssp10/multi-tenant). Another example of creating new datasources:

```
@Autowired private Map <String, Datasource> mars2DataSources;

public void addDataSourceAtRuntime() {

    DataSourceBuilder dataSourcebuilder = DataSourcebuilder.create(
        MultiTenantJPAConfiguration.class.getclassloader())
            .driverclassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
            .username("postgres")
            .password("postgres")
            .url("Jdbc: postgresql://localhost:5412/somedb");

        mars2DataSources("tenantX", datasourcebuilder.build())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this situation is adding `@RefreshScope` to the bean definition:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@RefreshScope
public DataSource routeDataSource() {

    RoutingDataSource routeDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();

    DataSource defaultDataSource = (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource");

    List<EstCredentials> credentials = LocalDataSourcesDetailsLoader.getAllCredentails(defaultDataSource); // fetching from database table

    localDataSourceRegistrationBean.registerDataSourceBeans(estCredentials);

    routeDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource);
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

    for (Credentials credential : credentials) {
        targetDataSources.put(credential.getEstCode().toString(),
                (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean(credential.getEstCode().toString()));
    }
    routeDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

    return routeDataSource;
}
```

Add Spring Boot Actuator as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then trigger the refresh endpoint `POST to /actuator/refresh` to update the DataSource (actually every refresh scoped bean).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using Oracle, you could also use its database change notification features.

Think of it as a listener in the JDBC driver that gets notified whenever something changes in your database table. So upon receiving a change, you could reinitialize/add datasources.

You can find a tutorial of how to do this here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28820

Though, depending on your organization database notifications need some extra firewall settings for the communication to work.

Advantage: You do not need to manually call the REST Endpoint if something changes, (though Marcos Barberios answer is perfectly valid!)